# ¿Cómo agregar un event listener para varios elementos?

Tags: javascript

Quiero añadir el evento `listener` a una lista de imágenes, cuando el mouse se encuentre sobre una imagen se extraiga el atributo alt de la imagen y lo coloque en un , obtuve la lista de todas las imágenes que necesito con:

`var img = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedorIMG')`

Pero puesto que esto me devuelve una lista a la que puedo acceder a sus elementos sólo colocando el indice (img[i]), quiero añadir un event listener para cualquiera de sus elementos, sin embargo no se como hacerlo. Pueden darme una mano? Lo que tengo de código es lo siguiente:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedorIMG'),
        titular = document.querySelector('#titular');


    img[0].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {     
        titular.innerText = 'CSS Master';
        console.log('Click');
    })
}
```

Obviamente está mal, pero es más o menos la idea que tengo por los momentos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Codigo

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var imagenes = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedorIMG');
  var titular = document.querySelector('#titular');

  for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {

    imagenes[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      titular.innerText = this.alt;
    });

  }
}
```

```html
<h2 id="titular"></h2>
<img height="42" width="42" class="contenedorIMG" alt="Imagen 1" src="https://ugc.kn3.net/i/origin/http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HiWHxDwh6TE/TrlrCVirYbI/AAAAAAAAAdU/-8d44aYfaVo/s1600/Mangekyou+Sharingan.png"></img>
<img height="42" width="42" class="contenedorIMG" alt="Imagen 2" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/132335/isolated/lists/4af43ce1082231cba5e5aa60fbb03f2f-staffs-iconos-de-c-rculo.png"></img>
<img height="42" width="42" class="contenedorIMG" alt="Imagen 3" src="https://students.faith.sa.edu.au/images/tiles/dropbox-icon.png"></img>
```

---

### Explicacion

Lo primero que hemos hecho es dejar cambiar la asociacion de los eventos usando esta sentencia:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {

    imagenes[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      titular.innerText = this.alt;
    });

  }
```

Lo que hacemos aqui es ir recorriendo cada uno de los elementos del arreglo `imagenes` y le iremos asociando el evento.

Posteriormente agregamos esta linea dentro de nuestra funcion a ejecutar:

```
titular.innerText = this.alt;
```

Con esta linea le indicamos al elemento `<h2>` el texto que tendra, cuando se cumpla el evento. Que para dicho caso sera agregar el atributo `alt` de la imagen a la que se esta asignando el evento.

---

### Actualizacion

Agrego una actualizacion respectiva al codigo que acabamos de trabajar, podria ser util para un caso que quieras que se oculte automaticamente el texto del titular.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var imagenes = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedorIMG');
  var titular = document.querySelector('#titular');

  for (var i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {

    imagenes[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      titular.innerText = this.alt;
    });

    imagenes[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
      titular.innerText = "";
    });

  }
}
```

```css
#contenedor_titular {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor_titular">
  <h2 id="titular"></h2>
</div>
<div>
  <img height="42" width="42" class="contenedorIMG" alt="Imagen 1" src="https://ugc.kn3.net/i/origin/http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HiWHxDwh6TE/TrlrCVirYbI/AAAAAAAAAdU/-8d44aYfaVo/s1600/Mangekyou+Sharingan.png"></img>
  <img height="42" width="42" class="contenedorIMG" alt="Imagen 2" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/132335/isolated/lists/4af43ce1082231cba5e5aa60fbb03f2f-staffs-iconos-de-c-rculo.png"></img>
  <img height="42" width="42" class="contenedorIMG" alt="Imagen 3" src="https://students.faith.sa.edu.au/images/tiles/dropbox-icon.png"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente Ivan, muchas gracias!

Comment: @PedroFumero Que bien que te haya servido, he agregado una actualizacion que podria ser de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien el problema que tienes, pero me supongo que lo que quieres es añadir un evento para cada elemento de tu array `img`. Esto lo podrías hacer con un bucle `for`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedorIMG'),
        titular = document.querySelector('#titular');

        for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

           img[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {     
           titular.innerText = 'CSS Master';
           console.log('Click');
           })
        }
}
```

Espero que esto responda a tu pregunta. Si no es así, intenta ofrecer algo más de información.

Comment: Perfecto amigo, es justo lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la respuesta del compañero @DanielGS cada listener asociado al evento puedes obtener el objeto asociado al evento con la sentencia this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var img = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedorIMG'),
    var titular = document.querySelector('#titular');

    for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
       img[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {     
       titular.innerText = this.alt;
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración.